# Model relationship in rails and their handling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model, relationship

I have a requirement for an app where two models invoice and message needs to be linked. The link/relationship should be able to do following things:

1. The invoice should be able to store the message_id.
2. The message should also be able to store the invoice_id - a foreign key to the invoice table.

There are some extra fields in both models.

Also can you tell me how will i be able to generate a `form_for` for this kind of models, where two models get data at the same time but of different fields. Should i use hidden_fields?

Please Help.

Comment: There is no such assocation that two sides all need to store the conterpart's id in its own table. Please describe the user case/business purpose instead of implementation.

Comment: This is a requirement when new invoice is received with new message. Both needs to point each other so that a user can view the new messages, new invoice.

Comment: You don't need to have both keys. Usually one of these relations is more important(parent) so it will has_one child association that belong_to it. Check my answer and read Rails associations guide I linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here You will learn about has_one and belong_to associations, which can be used with table structure You are searching for (though without extra explanation it sounds odd).

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association

After linking You models check nested attributes Railscasts to get and idea how You can construct form for multiple elements with mass-assignment supported:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2